# foldl compiles but not foldr

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

As a small exercise, I am trying to recode all. This code seems to work (except for infinite list):

```
allComp f acc x = acc && f x

all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all f xs = foldl (allComp f) True xs
```

But this one does not compile if I keep the same signature:

```
allComp f acc x = acc && f x

all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
all f xs = foldr (allComp f) True xs
```

And the compilation error is:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `Bool'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
      at Main.hs:8:8
Expected type: Bool -> Bool
  Actual type: a -> Bool
In the first argument of `allComp', namely `f'
In the first argument of `foldr', namely `(allComp f)'
In the expression: foldr (allComp f) True xs
```

Can anyone explain more clearly why the first version compiles but not the second?

Comment: Look at the type signatures for `foldl` and `foldr`. Hint: they're different.

Comment: Also, if you are new to types, you can enter into ghci `:t allComp` to see its type signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do a search on [*Hoogle*](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) you will see that the signature of `foldl` and `foldr` differ:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Now let's make the signature more *semantically sound*:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldr :: (b -> a -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
```

You see that the order of the types in the first argument (the function) differ. This is because `foldl` looks like:

```
foldl f z [x1,x2,...,xn] = f (f (f (... (f z x1) x2) x3)...) xn
```

whereas `foldr` looks like:

```
foldr f z [x1,x2,...,xn] = f z (f x1 (f x2 (... (f xn-1 xn) ...)))
```

Since the `(&&)` is associative, that does not matter much. You can simply change it with a `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c`:

```
all f xs = foldr (flip (allComp f)) True xs
```